# DateTimeOffset change offset to specific timezone

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime, datetimeoffset

I want to save a DateTimeOffset in my database as the timezone I provide

When I get a date from the frontend of my application, it is passed in as UTC time.

In the database, I dont want this: `2020-06-24 20:00:00.000000 +00:00`, I want this: `2020-06-24 16:00:00.000000 -04:00`

The reason I want to do this is because we have some legacy functions and stored procedures in SQL Server that don't consider the timezone, but we still want to look things up on the right date. Ex: an event occurred at 6/25 at 11PM EST, would be currently saved as 6/26 3AM UTC. Now if we look up all events for 6/25, the 6/25 11PM event wouldn't show up. This is why I want to save it as EST on the database.

I have looked at `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime` but that only takes in and returns a DateTime, not a DateTimeOffset

I really am looking for something that is like `DateTimeOffset.ConvertTo(TimeZoneInfo)`, but I have yet to find a good solution that also takes care of DST

Comment: You can't handle DST with just an offset. A lot of countries and timezones may have the same offset at some time but different DST rules. You need to actually know the timezone name. As for SQL Server, all versions since 2005 have a `datetimeoffset` type but again, that just stores the offest, not the actual timezone name

Comment: You are taking the wrong approach.  You always store data in a database in UTC.  You want to take local time and convert to UTC and then look up.  The DateTime object is already in UTC so I do not think you need any convert.

Comment: BTW `EST` isn't a standardized timezone name. There may be multiple timezones with those initials. For example IST can be Ireland Standard Time, Israel Standard Time or India Standard Time. The only de-facto standard is the IANA timezone databse (tzdb) and names like eg `Europe/Berlin`. You can use NodaTime to handle timezones and conversions

Comment: @jdweng I know what the right approach is, but unfortunately I have to deal with legacy reports that don't consider it.

Comment: @jdweng storing UTC won't help with DST and actually loses the original information. The only way is to store the actual timezone name along with the time

Comment: This is a design issue.  Suppose you have stores in USA in all 4 timezones what do you want to be the end of the business day?  Most companies pick  a common time for each of day (4 AM EST) rather than midnight where the store is located.

Comment: Design issue? USA in all 4 timezones? What if you then open a store in Europe? Or Asia? Will you **redesign** whole system's Date-Time handling because we've got a new deployment site? In the example you provided, **if** there is a need to have a "end of a business day", it should be local-wise, and the design of the global part of the system should consider that "day ends" at various moments in different places. Unless you are 100% sure that either there won't be any weird sites or 100% sure that you will be able to pay the cost of the software change (or lost opportunities w/o that change).

Comment: @jdweng cool man, do you have any real advice?

Comment: Most large companies use one end of business day for bookkeeping.  Some use by regions.    When you have one central computer office you have to track inventory and what inventory date do you use when you have offices around the world?  Usually you will pick a time when all stores are closed.

Comment: The correct date should be the business date and not actual date.  If you have a store that closes a 2:00 AM the business date is the previous date.

Comment: Can you pass it off to SQL Server?
`declare @dtz datetimeoffset = '2020-06-24 20:00:00.000000 +00:00';
select @dtz, @dtz at time zone 'US Eastern Standard Time'
`

`2020-06-24 20:00:00.0000000 +00:00 2020-06-24 16:00:00.0000000 -04:00`

Answer (score 1):

This is how I ended up solving this problem. This will convert it to the proper timezone, in this case

```
private DateTimeOffset ChangeTimezone(DateTimeOffset originalTime)
{
        TimeZoneInfo tzi = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central America Standard Time");
        return originalTime.ToOffset(tzi.GetUtcOffset(originalTime));
}
```

In my tests, this preserves DST too. For example, the offset would be -5 for Central Time and -6 during daylight savings time.